# Why is it required to mention JAVA_HOME path in double quotes when setting environment variable in windows

Tags: java, classpath

I am setting environment variables in windows Java_Home path using cmd. when I use 
`SETX JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07` it gives me error as Invalid syntax. But when I use
`SETX JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07"` it is set successfully.

When I set `SETX HOME C:\Users\Default` it sets successfully without double quotes. So why do we need double quotes only for `JAVA_HOME` and not for `HOME`?

Comment: Mostly because it has spaces in the path name...

Comment: This is not a Java question, it's a Windows command prompt question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "Program Files" contains a space. And I believe you mean

```
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07"
```

But Java 1.6.0 is unsupported (since February 2013), you should upgrade. Java 7 is [EOL in April 2015](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html), so I think it might be best to consider Java 8.